# Splitting a string to a list of integers in java

Tags: java, split, int

I want to split a string of form:

```
" 42 2152 12 3095 2"
```

into a list of integers, but when I use the `.split(" ")` function I end up with an empty `""` element at the beginning due to the whitespace at the start. Is there a way to split this without the empty element?

Comment: uses s.trim().split(" ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *String.trim()* function before you call split on the array. This will remove any white-spaces before and after your original string

**For example:**

```
    String original = " 42 2152 12 3095 2"; 
    original = original.trim();
    String[] array = original.split(" ");
```

To make your code neater, you could also write it as:

```
    String original = " 42 2152 12 3095 2"; 
    String[] array = original.trim().split(" ");
```

If we print the array out:

```
    for (String s : array) {
        System.out.println(s);
     }
```

The output is:

```
42
2152
12
3095
2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.trim` to remove leading and trailing whitespace from the original string

```
String withNoSpace = " 42 2152 12 3095 2".trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Scanner` , it will read one integer at a time from string

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(number);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    list.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Would this method be faster than the trim + split method?

Answer (score 1):

As per above answers and you are asking the performance difference between all these methods:

There is no real performance difference all of these would run with O(n).

Actually, splitting the strings first like , and then adding them to a collection will contain 2 x O(n) loops.